# Joint probability distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to calculate P(Y|Z) given the following distribution $\ P(X,Y,Z) = P(X)P(Z)P(Y|X,Z)$
Now, initially I did the following calculation.
$$P(Y|Z)=\sum_{x}^{}P(X,Y|Z)=\sum_{x}^{}P(X,Y,Z)/P(Z)=\sum_{x}^{}[P(X)P(Y|X)P(Z|X,Y)]/P(Z) $$

But this was wrong and the correct answer was $$P(Y|Z)=\sum_{x}^{}[P(X|Z)P(Y|X,Z)] = \sum_{x}^{}[P(X)P(Y|X,Z)]$$

**Note:**$\ P(X|Z) = P(X)$ as X and Z are independent of each other, given no knowledge of Y.

My question is the following. In my original solution, I considered X as my first "pick," if you will, Y as my second pick, and Z as my third pick. This given $\ P(X) * P(X|Y) * P(Z | X, Y) = P(XYZ)$. In the actual solution, they choose Z as the first pick, X as the second pick, and Y as the third pick. Then, P(Z) cancels out from the numerator and denominator leaving us with the correct answer. I understand why it makes more sense to choose Z as my first pick, because we are already given Z. However, why should I choose X as my second pick(giving me P(X|Z))? What is my motivation to choose X over Y as my second pick? I am very confused over this concept.

I see that in the original distribution, Y is dependent on X and Z, so it's just easier to use P(Y | X,Z). But I want to have a more concrete understanding of why so I am not just memorizing and picking things out.

Comment: Order does not matter, if P(X,Z)=P(X)P(Z) for every (X,Z) then P(Y|X)P(Z|X,Y)]/P(Z)=P(Y|X,Z) for every (X,Y,Z).

Comment: So does that mean that P(Y|X,Z) = P(Y)P(X|Y)P(Z|YX)? Don't we need to take the original distribution into account?

Comment: Sorry but you should be able to see right away that, in full generality, Bayes formula (or simply the definition of conditional distribution) yields  P(Y|X,Z) = P(X,Y,Z)/P(X,Z) while P(Y)P(X|Y)P(Z|Y,X) =  P(X,Y,Z) hence these do not coincide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the actual solution, they choose Z as the first pick, X as the second pick, and Y as the third pick.

What?   No, we just applied the Law of Total Probability and the definition of conditional probability.   These are general rules; they always apply.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(Y\mid Z) =&~ \sum_{X\in\mathcal X}\mathsf P(X,Y\mid Z) \\[1ex]=&~ \sum_{X\in\mathcal X}\dfrac{\mathsf P(X,Y,Z)}{\mathsf P(Z)}\end{align}$$

Then we use the given fact that $\mathsf P(X,Y,Z) = \mathsf P(X)~\mathsf P(Z)~\mathsf P(Y\mid X,Z)$.   This is a property specific to these three variables.   It's not always true, but it is here.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(Y\mid Z) =&~ \sum_{X\in\mathcal X}\dfrac{\mathsf P(X)~\mathsf P(Z)~\mathsf P(Y\mid X,Z)}{\mathsf P(Z)} \\[1ex]=&~ \sum_{X\in\mathcal X}\mathsf P(X)~\mathsf P(Y\mid X,Z)\end{align}$$

That is all.